# Voltages not what I expect when charging a capacitor with another

Tags: capacitor, parallel, charge

I experimented with charging a capacitor (in my case, 100 microfarad) from by power supply (to 10V) and connecting it parallel to another cap of the same capacitance, with the matching polarities together.

I read this derivation on what should happen:

https://www.edn.com/electronics-blogs/living-analog/4394290/Capacitor-charge-transfer-

I understand that half of the energy in the first, charged capacitor is lost. The voltage across both capacitors should now be half of the original voltage applied across the charged capacitor.

However, this is not what my oscilloscope shows! If I charge the first capacitor to 10V, and connect them, I see around 2 volts across. If I charge the first cap to 8V, I see around 1 volt across the two capacitors! Below is a picture of my setup, can anybody tell what is it that I'm doing wrong or what is happening here? Why am I not seeing half of the original applied voltage across the parallel capacitors?

[image]

To clarify, I first took the left capacitor to the left of the breadboard, connected the voltage from my supply across it, and then moved it parallel to the right capacitor. I've checked everything I can think of, all the connections are correct.. And I was careful moving the capacitors, I did not short the leads with my fingers or anything similar.

Comment: Are you confusing energy with voltage? Half the energy will be lost but E=(CU^2)/2

Comment: @winny But assuming the conservation of charge as in the link, and that the combined capacitance of the parallel system is twice that of the single capacitor: charge = 100 microfarad * 10V = 1000 microcoulomb. Then, as voltage = charge / capacitance : 1000 microcoulomb / 200 microfarad = 5. So I should expect 5 volts, right?

Comment: Were both empty? If yes, swap the capacitors. Is the result still same? You can measure the capacitances measuring the time constant with a resistor, say 220kOhm. Note: the input of the scope must be taken into the account, too. Electrolytics also dig out some charge  from slow chemical processes long after they are discharged.

Comment: @user287001 Yes, both were empty. Now I switched them, and I seem to get even more bizarre results: Now the scope shows 10V across the parallel combination..

Comment: measure the time constants! Charge both to 10V and measure how long it takes to discharge to 3,7V through the same resistor, say 220kOhm. Your capacitors can be remarkably different regardless of printed texts.

Comment: Did it arc when you connected them together? You can lose a whack of energy in that little event.

Comment: @user287001 Okay, I took another pair of capacitors from another batch and they behave as expected! It seems that the batch of capacitors I used initially was somehow dodgy, I will have to bring this up with the store I bought them from.. Thanks for the answers though!

Comment: User specific part issue solved by experimentation.

Comment: @Trevor Arcing, ohmic losses in metal and radiowaves are the usual ways which waste the obligatory lost energy. The charge stays, half of the energy is lost.

Comment: @user287001 indeed the energy is dissipated into a magnetic field, but arcing is not normally part of that group. A 1000C arc burns off a lot of energy. Anyhoos. he fixed it, making the question redundant.

Comment: @user287001 I'm not going to get into this argument with you.

Comment: No need to argumentation - it's useless.  The energy dissipation in all possible ways are in OP's switching case =50%, no matter occurs there some arcing or not and no matter, what opinions we have.

Comment: @user287001, `half of the energy is lost` ... energy does not get lost, it just moves to a different place

Comment: V2(C1+C2)=C1V1  for initial cap C1 and initial voltage V1. Thus V reduction to 1/8th means 1/(1+7)  derives the C ratios

Comment: @jsotola The loss here in my texts = the percentage of energy which get converted to some other form than the electric field in those two capacitors. OP's case = two identical C:s are connected together, one C  has zero initial voltage and another has 10 volts. The voltage is assumed to stabilize to a constant DC value.

Comment: @user287001 the energy is not lost. The issue with the capacitor paradox, water tank paradox and spring paradox is not that energy mysteriously disappears but rather that peoples concept of what the energy level of the system was at the start of the transfer is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But here's still no answer. It's corrected now:

The practical tests that I suggested in the comments, mainly swapping the capacitors, showed that they have radically different capacitances. Get new capacitors which are less different, then you get something more like the expected result.

The expected result, when two equal capacitors are connected parallel and one of them had 0V inital voltage and another had 10V: Both have 5V and the total energy stored in the capacitors as static electric field energy is halved, 50% is dissipated as heat and electromagnetic radiation.